# Installed but cannot seen on apt-cache

Tags: apt, software-installation, ffmpeg, apt-cache

I have installed ffmpeg and libx264 via that code. I can use ffmpeg and can do simple jobs but if i write apt-cache ffmpeg it returns me Installed: (none) Why i cannot see it in apt-cache?

```
    # build and install x264
git clone --depth 1 git://git.videolan.org/x264
cd x264
./configure --host=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi --enable-static --disable-opencl
make -j 4
sudo make install

# build and make ffmpeg
git clone --depth=1 git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git
cd ffmpeg
./configure --arch=armel --target-os=linux --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
make -j4
sudo make install
```

Error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/var/www/html/GetVideo $ apt-cache policy ffmpeg
ffmpeg:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7:3.2.10-1~deb9u1+rpt1
  Version table:
     7:3.2.10-1~deb9u1+rpt1 500
        500 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7:3.2.10-1~deb9u1 500
        500 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf Packages
pi@raspberrypi:/var/www/html/GetVideo $
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compile and install whatever you want to from source, but to integrate it into the package management system you need to use an additional tool such as `checkinstall` instead of `make install`.

```
./configure
make
sudo checkinstall --pkgname=my-compiled-package --pkgversion="99:$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)-git" --default
```